# linked list: strange muddle of member element during output

Tags: c, linked-list, dynamic-memory-allocation

**Problem statement**: Given a list of countries and number of females and males that participated in some particular survey. Program is to sort the list in descending order regarding number of males and females summed up, reading the list from SecondaryEd2005.txt file. Problem have to be solved using linked list only, not double linked list. No presorting using arrays is permitted. Members have to be: char pointer to country name, 2 longs for number of female and male participants. Space for country name have to be dynamically allocated. Output have to be in format like country name, number of female participants, number of male participants, sum of them, end of the line.

**Issue**: in any case the code outputs the last country name read, while it gives right output about number of males and females and their sum, they are in descending order. I tried to output the members of the new node before it is put in the right place of the list and it gives correct output, signalling that everything is read correctly. 
I think there is something with country name being dynamically allocated, but not sure about it and in case it is correct, don't know what exactly. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct _person_count {
    char* country;
    long females;
    long males;
    struct _person_count *link;
} person_count;

int main () {
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("SecondaryEd2005.txt","r");

    person_count *first = NULL;

    char c[32];
    int male;
    int female;

    do {
        person_count *newNode = malloc(sizeof(person_count));
        fscanf(file, "%s %i %i %i", c, &female, &male);
        newNode->females = female;
        newNode->males = male;
        int n;

        n = strlen(c);
        newNode->country = malloc(n*sizeof(char));
        newNode->country = c;
    newNode->link = NULL;
        printf("still reading: %s %i %i \n", newNode->country, newNode->females, newNode->males);

        if(first == NULL) {
            first = newNode;
        } else {
            int sumnewNode = newNode->females + newNode->males;
            int sumFirst = first->females + first->males;

            if(sumnewNode > sumFirst) {
                newNode->link = first;
                first = newNode;
            }else {
                person_count* current = first;
                while (1)
                {
                    if (current->link == NULL)
                    {
                        current->link = newNode;            
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (current->link->females + current->link->males < sumnewNode)
                    {
                        newNode->link = current->link;
                        current->link = newNode;
                        break;
                    }
                    current = current->link;
                }
            }
        }
    } while(!feof(file));


    person_count* cur = first;

    while(1)
    {
    printf("%s %d %d %d\n", cur->country, cur->females, cur->males, cur->females + cur->males);
        if (cur->link == NULL)
            break;
        cur = cur->link;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

If any additional information is needed I can provide it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several bugs here:

```
    n = strlen(c);
    newNode->country = malloc(n*sizeof(char));
    newNode->country = c;
```

C strings are supposed to be NUL-terminated, and `strlen()` doesn't account for this.  Perhaps using `strdup()` would be better here:

```
    newNode->county = strdup(c);
```

You will still need to `free()` the memory later when you tear down the list.

Also, your version leaks memory since you never actually use the buffer you allocated.  This line:

```
    newNode->country = c;
```

sets country to point to a buffer on the stack, which will go away, leaving your pointer pointing at invalid memory--or worse, valid memory that is not your own.  At the very least, it's getting clobbered for each line scanned, which is making all of your nodes point to the last country read.  If you're going to stick with allocating your own memory, it should be more like:

```
    newNode->country = calloc((n+1) * sizeof(char));
    strncpy(newNode->country, c, n);
```

Comment: Thanks for deep explanation. Used to use standard library in c++, thus have very weak knowledge of implementation of list.

Answer (score 1):

[strlen()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen) returns length of string **without** null terminator. That's important (basically you want `newNode->country = malloc(n+1);`, `sizeof(char)` is always 1).

What's worse, after that you rewrite `newNode->country`, losing pointer to allocated block and setting `newNode->country` to point at your 32-char buffer (so in the end `country` pointers in all nodes point to the same string). String copying should be made with [strncpy() or strncpy_s()](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncpy) call.